# Run / emitter event from one component to another

Tags: angular, typescript

I created two components: (`nav` and `app`).

Within the nav I have the function `getnumber()` which when executed subtracts -1 from the total value.

Is there a way to execute this function through a click but in the app component?

I intend that when clicking the button of the app component the function will be executed in the `nav` component and the value updated.

As the total value is 5, when clicking the button the function is executed and the value becomes 4.

Can anyone help me apply this?

Thanks

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pr8mos?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnav%2Fnav.component.ts)

**nav.ts**

```
getnumber(){
  this.total = this.total - 1;
}
```

**Nav.html**

```
<p>
Nav
</p>

<p>
Total: {{total}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call public methods on another component via a template reference.

app.component.html

```
<app-nav #nav></app-nav>

<button (click)="nav.decrement()">
  Execute decrement() nav component
</button>
```

nav.component.ts

```
total = 5;

decrement() {
  this.total = this.total - 1;
}
```

In the HTML example, `#nav` is creating a reference called `nav` to the `NavComponent` instance. Any other elements in the same HTML file can now call public functions on that instance.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bw5jtp

### Alternative approach

Instead of calling `#nav` directly in the HTML, you can call it from your component.ts. Use `@ViewChild` to get a reference to the instance of the component.

app.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('nav', { static: true }) nav: NavComponent;

onClick(): void {
  this.nav.decrement();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Is there a way to execute this function without directly using the click? In other words, I click on the button to run a function in the app and within that function I run the one on the navbar, is it possible to do this?

Comment: You could bind the click event to a function in `app.component.ts`, which then calls the `#nav` instance that is injected into `app.component.ts` via a `@ViewChild()`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I've updated my answer and demo to show you how to call from your component.ts file