# Emitting an event on a component so that a function of a distinct component is performed

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component with several routes (home, app and navbar).

I intend that by pressing the navbar button, the `encrementcalc()` function will be executed. Is there any way to implement this? I tried to use the event emitter but without success :(

Can someone help me?

thank you.

Link to the example here [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-66soy2?file=src%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts)

**code**

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/home']">home</a></li>
      <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/navbar']">navbar</a></li>
          </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

[image: Imagem]

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run / emitter event from one component to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341126/run-emitter-event-from-one-component-to-another)

Comment: @KurtHamilton 
I tried but it didn't work, is it because of using routes? Thanks for the reply

Comment: What you are trying to do makes no sense. When the navbar component is active, there is no home component instance to call. They are mutually exclusive. One or the other will appear inside `<router-outlet>` at any given time

Comment: Components live for as long as you can see them. Once you navigate from home to navbar, the home component will die, along with all of the state it is storing.

Comment: And I believe this is a duplicate of the question I linked to because I believe you are both trying to answer the same question, it's just that you have structured yours slightly differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a service, that shares informations between navbar and home component(or other component)
 this is an example of the service

```
    @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'})

    export class NavbarService {
      attttributeChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
      constructor() {}

      emitAttributeChange(attribute: number) {
        this.sortAttributeChange.emit(sortAttribute);
      }
      getNavChangeEmitter() {
        return this.attributeChange;
      }
    }
```

So to your navbar copmponent you add

```
EncrementInHome(){
  this.navbarService.emitAttributeChange(5);
}
```

an then in your home component in your OnInit method you get the sent data

```
     ngOnInit() {
            this.subscription$ =                    
            this.navbarService.getNavChangeEmitter().subscribe(
          newChangeAttribute => {
          this.encrementcalc()
          });
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help? Can you post the link to help others with the same problem? I'll try to apply it to mine too

Comment: @SteveMc link of what ?

Comment: If you put a link (stackblitz) with your implementation it would help a lot. I tried to implement this, but the value did not change

Comment: @SteveMc in this link i send 7 from navbar to home component https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4dqbvl?file=src%2Fnavbar%2Fnavbar.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a service for communication in your case.

first create a `increment.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class IncrementService {
  private calcSource = new Subject<any>();

  calc$: Observable<any> = this.calcSource.asObservable();

  increment(x: number) {
    this.calcSource.next(x);
  }
}
```

then in your `NavbarComponent`

```
  import {IncrementService} from '../increment.service'

  constructor(private _incrementService: IncrementService) {}

  incrementInHome() {
    this._incrementService.increment(7);
  }
```

finaly, in your `HomeComponent`

```
  import {IncrementService} from '../increment.service'

  calc = 5;
  constructor(private _incrementService: IncrementService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._incrementService.calc$.subscribe(x => this.calc += x)
  }
```

Comment: how is that ? @SteveMc

Comment: Gives this error: _co.EncrementInHome is not a function

Comment: i changed the names of your function to `incrementInHome()`

Comment: Now there is no error, but the value does not change when I click

Answer (score 0):

By the way your components are set up, I would suggest you use a service. Inside the service you would have a property that maintains the state and other  methods to retrieve and modify it. You would then use this service from the nav bar to increment the property and from the home component to retrieve the current value.

Comment: I tried to use it as a service and then execute the function, but the page value does not update